# Javascript function onclick is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to launch some action on button click so I defined a function and passed a php value as a parameter that I'm getting from a controller and I'm willing to use this parameter value to pass some parameter through ajax to another controller.

So I'm setting the function that lunch the function in a button

```
        <button type="" onclick="CreateCommende('<?php echo $username;  ?>')"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Valider</button>
```

then I'm trying to see if it's retrieving the right PHP value in a script part :

```
    function CreateCommende(username)
    {
        var name = username;
        console.log(name);
    }
    ;
```

here I can see that It's reading the right PHP value :
[image]

but when I pass `CreateCommende('admin')` in my console I get this

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CreateCommende is not defined
>       at :1:1

What's the problem?

Comment: Its hard to tell without getting the full context of how your code is setup.

Comment: did you define the function before or after your button?

Comment: how do you render the `CreateCommende()` function?

Comment: The problem is that `CreateCommade` is not defined at the point it is being used. There are a number of things that could cause that, and without more code and complete example it is going to be hard defining the root cause.

Comment: It says `CreateCommende` is not defined, so the PHP isn't relevant and how you load the JS to defined `CreateCommende` is (as is code around the definition of `CreateCommende` … which might not be a global, or which might throw errors)

Comment: I edited the post with some explanation! I'm not sure which part of the code I should share too to make clear. I'm using CodeIgniter and the function is placed inside script with some other functions which are working fine

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the script is placed before the closing `</body>` tag

```
<script>
 function CreateCommende(username)
    {
        var name = username;
        console.log(name);
    }
    ;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter, So I'm placing the script inside a script tag with some different functions which are working fine

Answer (score 0):

the javascript function is not loaded in a file or script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CreateCommende(username)
  {
    var name = username;
    console.log(name);
  };
</script>
<button type="" onclick="CreateCommende('<?php echo $username;  ?>')"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Valider</button>
```

to avoid broken markup you can escape your output with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

```
<?php echo addslashes($username); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by placing the function code outside:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {}
```